# Getting accurate daily U.S. populations

Tags: data, census, united-states, population

I suppose you could interpolate from the Census data, but is there a data feed that has accurate DAILY total population of the U.S.?

The finer the granularity, the better (so if there was daily populations by state or county that would be great).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to get data that is varying over time, and doesn't ask anything about geography (other than "if I can get populations by state/county") -- Migrate to opendata.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Due to the uncertainty in extrapolation, the US Census normally won't even provide *annual* county population estimates (except for a few extremely large counties).

Comment: Sorry if this was off topic.

Comment: It doesn't exist. The amount of coordination it would require to get accurate daily estimates for the United States would be an immense cost and an insane burden. Not only would it require all hospitals, police, and county governments to contribute to the Vital Statistics on a regular basis (something the CDC struggles with even today), it would require accurate immigration and emigration counts which definitely don't exist.

Comment: Thank you Kotebiya. I suppose I just want the most granular data possible. If it is monthly or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

From the US Census http://www.census.gov/popclock/ it appears to be updated by the second.

Comment: That site just adds a new person every 12 seconds.  It is not getting any data feeds to make it this accurate.

Comment: I'm looking for a more methodical approach, but thanks for pointing this out.